# Function not working at one place

Tags: php, functions

```
function some_function() {
    $template_options = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'the_s_t_l_id', true);
    if ('layout_7' === $template_options || 'layout_8' === $template_options || 'layout_9' === $template_options){
        echo 'displaynone';
    }
}
```

Class →

```
.displaynone {display:none;}
```

But when I am calling function it doesnt work here →

```
<aside class="sidebar <?php some_function(); ?>">
```

However, if I call this function somewhere else, and if the logic is true then it does print the anticipated class.

what is the reason that it is not working in the desirable place then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have functions that work only inside of the WordPress Loop like `get_the_id()`. This will return the correct value inside the WP Loop in template files, but when called in other places does not return the correct value and check fails.

See this for more information on the WordPress loop

https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

When outside the loop you can either use the global `$post` object to get the id like this

```
global $post
$id = $post->ID;
```

Alternately you can try this

```
$id = get_queried_object_id();
```

Comment: Actually, when I write the whole loop within the function it worked for me. I don't know if writing the loop within the function is a great/correct method or not.